# Was my MacBook hacked if I have PuTTY host keys in my home directory?

Tags: macos, security, putty

`.putty/randomseed` and `.putty/sshhostkeys` were found in my home directory of my MacBook Pro this morning.

I'm running OS X Snow Leopard. I've never installed PuTTY on my machine.

Does this mean my machine has been compromised, and by a Windows computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=ab11c0c6448d7060bc92e8820ddb0af4), it's a sign of a Windows trojan only (?).

On Unix, PuTTY actually stores its data under `~/.putty`, so [that's normal too](http://putty.cs.utah.edu/faq.html#faq-settings). So, no harm done – but just to be safe, and if you don't actually use PuTTY, delete the whole directory.

As always, make sure you don't have any Sharing options enabled under *System Preferences* that you don't want. You can also check open internet connections with `sudo lsof -i` for anything suspicious.

Answer (score 4):

Noticed the same thing today, found ~/.putty/sshhostkeys containing keys for some DB servers I use frequently.  I was pretty concerned.. turns out that it was created after using a SQL GUI client.  It had a feature to connect to your DB via SSH Tunnel. instead of using  ~/.ssh directory it creates a .putty directory and stores its host keys there.

Answering a really old question, but I noticed this today as well.  As this was 4th Google hit for ".putty osx" and the accepted answer not being very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I can even clarify this furthers.

This directory is created by Filezilla for OS X. You can safely delete it and start Filezilla again.

You will then see Filezilla complaining about a syntax error, and every host you try to connect from your address book will throw an "Unknown Hostkey" info.

Comment: There appear to be plenty of other apps that will also create it.  On my system it's timestamped to about 2 minutes after I upgraded XCode to v9.1, and the file inside is being used reasonably frequently, so I suspect that XCode is touching it every time it restarts.